# django imagefield save NoneType Object error

Tags: python, django, django-models

How can I upload images with imagefield? The following is giving me a `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'chunks'`.

I believe I am doing this wrong, can someone show me the correct way of doing this?

This is what I have so far for saving the uploaded image.

```
def add_employee(request):

if request.method == 'POST':
    form_input = AddEmployee(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form_input.is_valid():
        cd = form_input.cleaned_data
        new_emp = Employees(
                first_name = cd['first_name']
                .....
            )

        new_emp.save()
        photo_file = cd['photo_file']
        new_emp.photo.save('filename', photo_file)

     return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
```

forms.py and models.py

```
class AddEmployee(forms.Form):
      ...
      photo_file = forms.ImageField(required=False)

class Employees(models.Model):
      ...
      photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='employee_photos', blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: It is very difficult to help you if you do not provide a full stack trace. We have no idea where your AttributeError comes from.

Comment: @andreaspelme it comes from this line `new_emp.photo.save('filename', photo_file)`

Answer (score 1):

Okay after some digging around I found out what the problem was.

`request.FILES` is getting nothing, hence the `NoneType` i needed to add `enctype=multipart/form-data` in my form in order for the request to work.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be using modelforms. With a modelform, your code would look something like this:

in forms.py:

```
from django import forms

from .models import Employees

class EmployeeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Employees
```

in views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

from .forms import EmployeeForm

def add_employee(request):
    form = EmployeeForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')

    return render(request, 'your_template.html', {'form': form})
```

This is the standard/best practice way to deal with forms that are related to models. The `request.POST or None` is a trick to avoid having to check `request.method == 'POST'`.

This is the simple case, you can easily add select fields to be included/excluded from your model, add extra fields for a specific form, add extra logic to be run before your model is saved, or add custom validation.

See the documentation for `ModelForms`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/